# Run a string as lua code to call a function with only the function name

Tags: lua, lua-5.1, defold

I am making a dynamic callback table for a helper function that handles input events.
I want to make `a(testString)` execute when `functionTable[1](testString)` executes or allow a way for it to be run directly from a string.

```
functionTable = {}
testString = "atad atad atad"

function a(param)
    print(param)
end

functionTable[1] = "a"

exec(functionTable[1].."(testString)")
```

How should I be doing this?

(for Lua 5.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `load()` function to execute strings:

```lua
functionTable = {}
testString = "atad atad atad"

function a(param)
    print("hello " .. param)
end

functionTable[1] = "a"

load(functionTable[1].."(testString)")()
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Why is the second pair of parentheses necessary?

Comment: @GrifyDev it is because `load()` is a function that just collects a string and transforms it into a real execution, however it is necessary that we call the function inside load() so that we can actually execute it and collect its return

Comment: I meant the () here

Comment: load(functionTable[1].."(testString)")__()__

Comment: yes exactly, `load()` will only convert the string to an executable, but we still need to call it by the function being called inside `load()`